# Toggling an image with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a image, "sprites arrow-d", in a parent element ".learn-more".  If learn-more is clicked, i want arrow-d replaced by arrow-u and vice-versa.  What is the best way to write this.

```
$('.learn-more').click(function() {

    if ($('.arrow-d').is('arrow-d'))
    {
    $('#hero').animate({
        'height':'400'
    }, 700);
        $('.arrow-d').removeClass('arrow-d').addClass('arrow-u');
    }
    else 
    {
        $('.arrow-u').removeClass('arrow-u').addClass('arrow-d');
    }


});
```

html:

```
        <div class="learn-more">
            <span>LEARN MORE ABOUT</span>
            <i class="sprites arrow-d"></i>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.learn-more').on('click', function() {
    $('#hero').animate({'height': $('.arrow-d').length?400:80}, 700);
    $('.arrow-d').toggleClass('arrow-d arrow-u');
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method instead. That way you won't need to check if the classes are present or not. Something like this:

```
$('.learn-more').click(function() {
    $('#hero').animate({
        'height':'400'
    }, 700);
    $("i.sprites").toggleClass("arrow-d arrow-u");
});
```

Comment: Ok, and what about the animate above?  How can I toggle that back to say "80px"

Comment: @Josh Do you mean that you want to add 80px when clicked, and then remove those 80px when clicked again?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.learn-more').click(function() {

    var sprites = $(this).find('sprites');
        if (sprites.hasClass('arrow-d'))
        {
$('#hero').animate({
        'height':'400px'
    }, 700);
            sprites.removeClass('arrow-d').addClass('arrow-u');
        }
        else 
        {
$('#hero').animate({
        'height':'80px'
    }, 700);
            sprites.removeClass('arrow-u').addClass('arrow-d');
        }

    });
```